# Set a specific page as homepage

Tags: home-url

I use DIVI and i need to have a custom page (build with theme builder) set as the homepage.
there is no shortcode available for this page, so i use a simple redirection
ex [www.myste.com/](http://www.myste.com/) ---> [www.mysite.com/prodcut/myproduct/](http://www.mysite.com/prodcut/myproduct/)
i guess thers is a better way to achieve that, maybe wp-config or functions.php...
any ideas please ?

Comment: You can do this using the general settings, there's no need to write code, just go into the options pages under settings in WP Admin and choose that page as your homepage

Comment: Is the page you want to set as a homepage a _page_, or a product? There's a big difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings > Reading you can choose any Page to be displayed as your home page.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work this way with DIVI/ theme builder page template

Comment: Why doesn't it? The page isn't in the list, or the template changes?

Comment: I use a template builder in DIVI for this page, it's a template for a custom woocommerce product.  i tried to display it with a shortcode but some feaures are missing.